# Brace-init-list and assignments

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, list-initialization

```
#include <iostream>

struct int_wrapper
{
    int i;

    int_wrapper(int i = 0) : i(i) {}
};

struct A
{
    int_wrapper i;
    int_wrapper j;

    A(int_wrapper i = 0, int_wrapper j = 0) : i(i), j(j) {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    a = {3};

    // error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘A’ and ‘int’)
    // a = 3;

    std::cout << a.i.i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know that isn't allowed more than one user-conversion when doing an implicit conversion, but, why with a brace-init-list the double user-conversion works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember: using a braced-init-list means "initialize an object". What you are getting is an implicit conversion followed by an object initialization. You're getting "double user-conversion" because that's what you *asked for*.

When you do `a = <something>;`, what this does is the effective equivalent of `a.operator=(<something>)`.

When that something is a braced-init-list, this means that it will do `a.operator=({3})`. That will pick an `operator=` overload, based on initializing their first parameter from a braced-init-list. The overload that will be called will be the one that takes a type which can be initialized by the values in the braced-init-list.

There are two overloads of that operator. Namely, the copy-assignment and move-assignment. Since this braced-init-list initializes a prvalue, the preferred function to call will be the move-assignment operator (not that this matters, since it all leads to the same thing). The parameter of the move-assignment is `A&&`, so the braced-init-list  will attempt to initialize an `A`. And it will do so via the rules of copy-list-initialization.

Having selected the `operator=` function to call, we now initialize `A`. Since the constructor of `A` is not `explicit`, copy-list-initialization is free to call it. Since that constructor has 2 default parameters, it can be called with only a single parameter. And the type of the first parameter in `A`'s constructor, `int_wrapper`, is implicitly convertible from the type of the first value in the braced-init-list, `int`.

So, you get an implicit conversion to `int_wrapper`, which is used by copy-list-initialization to initialize a prvalue temporary object, which is used to assign to an existing object of type `A` via move-assignment.

By contrast, `a.operator=(3)` attempts to implicitly convert from 3 to `A` directly. Which of course requires two conversion steps and therefore is not allowed.

Just remember that braced-init-lists mean "initialize an object".

Comment: You confused me a bit. One you say "a braced-init-list initializes a prvalue", then you say "braced-init-lists mean "initializes an object"". AFAIK a braced-init-list is a uniform way to initialize an object. What's up with the prvalue (I know what a prvalue is)? Maybe a bit of clarification is needed.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: Edited: "**this** braced-init-list initializes a prvalue". Since the overload selection selects a function taking a reference, it has to create a prvalue temporary and bind the reference to it.